# Visual Editor freezing on text highlight since 4.3

Tags: tinymce, visual-editor, table

Ever since I updated my website to 4.3 my visual editor is freezing every time I try to highlight a piece of text, or even place my cursor someplace random. This only seems to be happening on the text contained within a HTML table. When I open console tab in Chrome, following error is displayed over and over again:

```
    Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded -- tinymce.min.js?ver=4203-20150730:7
```

On a recommendation from people at WordPress forums I already tried disabling all of my addons, cleared my browser cache and my Cloudflare cache, and changed themes to Twenty Twelve. Nothing seems to help.

I even made a sub-domain, and installed a fresh copy of WordPress on it in order to test if my WordPress installation is broken. Nope. Same thing happens even on a completely new website running on 4.3.

I also have another website on the same host but I haven't updated it to 4.3 yet, and everything works smooth as ever there. No freezing whatsoever.

Another thing that I noticed is that the CPU usage on my PC goes to 60-70% when this error occurs, and then goes back to normal 2-5% when it unfreezes. I also recently updated to Windows 10, if that's of any importance.

To replicate this error, copy the HTML table code bellow and paste it couple of times in a new post - enough so that you can actually scroll the page. Then try scrolling the page in the Visual Editor with your mouse-wheel and while doing so try to select a piece of text. This without exception freezes my screen for good 4-5 seconds.

```
<h3>Title</h3>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr><td><p>Nulla ac vehicula nunc. Sed sed maximus lectus, a cursus ligula. Aliquam enim lacus, mollis quis vestibulum et, imperdiet et enim. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Curabitur eget gravida est, a vehicula tortor. Curabitur aliquam lorem justo, vitae maximus metus porttitor vel. Aliquam neque mauris, posuere a mauris sit amet, ullamcorper accumsan velit.</p><p>Aenean vitae condimentum lacus. Vivamus sit amet velit quis lectus dapibus laoreet. Fusce ultricies aliquet arcu ac lacinia. Vivamus a erat ut erat ornare bibendum vel vitae velit. Vestibulum ut tellus quis magna luctus scelerisque pulvinar sit amet orci. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In malesuada ligula in ante pharetra, id euismod est tempor.</p></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Any idea of what might be causing this?

EDIT: Just tried on couple of other computers just to rule it out, and it happened on each one them. Is it a problem caused by caching perhaps? I am using CloudFlare, but I already purged files multiple times. Some people that are experiencing similar issues said that updating PHP to 5.4 helped, but I'm already running that version.

EDIT: Filled out a bug report at https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/33617 Seems to be an issue with TinyMCE itself.

Comment: On your subdomain test install... it was still happening  with the default WordPress theme and no plugins activated?

Comment: I just tried it on two different 4.3 sites with your HTML and couldn't replicate it (in Firefox anyway). You might try [filing a bug](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/report/31?COMPONENT=TinyMCE). They have some good 'before you file' [steps for debugging](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/testing/reporting-bugs/#before-you-report-a-bug) that might be helpful too.

Comment: Yeah, it was happening on a completely fresh install of WordPress with no plugins and running the stock theme. Could it be a related to my hosting provider? I'm gonna try install a local copy with XAMP to rule it out.
Thanks for your feedback, I appreciate it.

Comment: It could be but it seems unlikely: it's a javascript error. Has it happened to you in more than one browser? If not, it could be a plugin in your browser.

Comment: Yes, it's happening in all browsers that I have installed (Chrome, Firefox, Edge). Mozilla reports following error: too much recursion tinymce.min.js:7:18942

Comment: Okay, I just installed XAMPP and WordPress on my local machine, with stock theme, new database, and no plugins, - and the error still persists. I think that rules out my host provider, and CloudFlare. Gonna look into filling a bug I guess.

Comment: So you've tried: Multiple computers (rules out a mouse problem), multiple server environments with a clean WP install and multiple browsers? And no one else is seeing it? Dayum man, all I got is "sorry"!

Comment: Yeah, tried on two different computers with two different operating systems. I'm also confused and still looking into what could I possibly be doing wrong, but I'm honestly clueless at this point. It seems like someone else would encounter the same error by now, but nope.
Anyways thanks for testing it out. Did you paste the code multiple times by the way? This only seems to be happening when there's a lot of tables in a post, and unfortunately that's how my content is organized atm.

Comment: I missed the 'multiple times' thing, sorry. Good news(?): I can reproduce the bug if I paste it in 4-5 times, scroll around and then try to select some text and italicize it.

Comment: Omg, that's a huge relief! Thanks! I usually have 10+ tables in a single post, and happens pretty much even if I just scroll down and try to place my cursor between any two words. It seems to be happening more often the further down you go on the page. 
Any idea of what might be causing it?